# Swift MVC Json Parsing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to parse from json url in my uicollectionview. can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my MODEL

```
init(carDetailDictionary: [String: Any]){
    self.regno = carDetailDictionary["regno"] as? String
    self.vin = carDetailDictionary["vin"] as? String
    self.timeStamp = carDetailDictionary["timestamp"] as? String
    self.fuel = carDetailDictionary["fuel"] as? String
}

static func fetchJson() -> [CarDetail]
{

    var carDetail = [CarDetail]()

    let jsonUrl = URL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sommestad/e38c1acf2aed495edf2d/raw/cdb6dfb85101eedad60853c44266249a3f4ac5df/vehicle-attributes.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrl!) { (data, responce, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error")
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data{

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    print(json)
                    for object in json!{
                        let newCar = CarDetail(carDetailDictionary: json!)
                        carDetail.append(newCar)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Json Loading error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return carDetail
}
```

View

class CarDetailCell: BaseCell {

```
var carDetail: CarDetail!{
    didSet{
        self.updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI() {

    carImageView.image = UIImage(named: "volvo")
    regnoLabel.text = carDetail.regno
    vinLabel.text = carDetail.vin
    brandLabel.text = carDetail.fuel
    timeStampLabel.text = carDetail.timeStamp
}
```

}

Here is My ViewController

var carDetails = CarDetail

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    carDetails = CarDetail.fetchJson()

   }
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return carDetails.count ?? 0

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CarDetailCell
    let car = carDetails[indexPath.row]
    cell.carDetail = car

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove all _non-relevant_ code

Comment: What is the problem? Only post code that is relevant to the problem. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your issue is not clear, but I notice that each time with webcall, the issue is that the call is async, so you can't do a return (`return carDetail`) directly. Use a closure, and then reload the data.

Comment: i can't parse from json. I don't know where is problem in my code.

Comment: Now i could parse but it has error (error processing json data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)

Answer (score 0):

Set the data and reload the tableView *after* the download finished:

```
class CarDetailController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var carDetails = [CarDetail]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Cars"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    // Registring cellID
    collectionView?.register(CarDetailCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
    collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
}

private func fetchJson() {      
    let jsonUrl = URL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sommestad/e38c1acf2aed495edf2d/raw/cdb6dfb85101eedad60853c44266249a3f4ac5df/vehicle-attributes.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrl!) { (data, responce, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error")
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data{

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    print(json)
                    for object in json!{
                        let newCar = CarDetail(carDetailDictionary: json!)
                        self.carDetail.append(newCar)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Json Loading error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, you need a capture list to prevent a retain cycle when using 'self' inside of a closure.

Comment: @dlbuckley as the class (self) does not hold a strong referenzen of the closure, there is no retain cycle.